# Installing Laravel with Docker /Sail; started to & deleted dir, then re-installed & says already exists but empty?

Tags: php, linux, laravel, docker, installation

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x#getting-started-on-linux

I created the install directory, `example-app`, ran the curl command, didn't run the sail up, but the directory was populated when I checked before removing it.

Then I repeated what I'd just did (changed my mind), but get this:

```
user@comp:~/Docker_$ curl -s "https://laravel.build/example-app?with=pgsql,mariadb,redis,memcached,meilisearch,minio,selenium,mailhog" | bash

 _                               _
| |                             | |
| |     __ _ _ __ __ ___   _____| |
| |    / _` | '__/ _` \ \ / / _ \ |
| |___| (_| | | | (_| |\ V /  __/ |
|______\__,_|_|  \__,_| \_/ \___|_|


In NewCommand.php line 194:
                               
  Application already exists!  
                               

new [--dev] [--jet] [--stack [STACK]] [--teams] [--prompt-jetstream] [-f|--force] [--] <name>


Get started with: cd example-app && ./vendor/bin/sail up
```

`example-app` is empty though?

Comment: Please share more details. Looks like there is an error message ("Application already exists!"). Also, how is this related to Linux or Docker?

Comment: I'm on linux following the instructions linked in this post for installing a docker container but I'm not experienced with docker